# SONAR issue "getxyz(String, String) may fail to clean up java.sql.ResultSet"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am facing the following SONAR issue with the code below:

> "getxyz(String, String) may fail to clean up java.sql.ResultSet"

even after closing `CallableStatement`

```
public String getxyz(String x, String y)

    throws DBException {

    CallableStatement castat = null;
    String result = null;
    try {

        castat = getConnection().prepareCall(

                "{call xyz_prc(?,?,?)}");

        castat.setString(1, y);

        castat.setString(2, x);

        castat.setString(3, "0");

        castat.executeQuery();
        result = castat.getString(4);

    } catch (SQLException se) {

        log.error("getxyz |  ::SQLException",se);

        throw new DBException(se.getMessage());

    } finally {

        try {

            if(castat!=null) {

                castat.close();

            }

        } catch (SQLException se) {

            log.error("getxyz |  ::SQLException",se);

        }

        closeConnection();
    }

    return result;
}
```

`CallableStatement` is only used in the method

Comment: I recommend switching to the more modern [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It's 2018 and nobody should be writing try/close/finally code by hand anymore.

Comment: What is your SonarQube version and version of installed plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
castat.executeQuery();
result = castat.getString(4);
```

You probably wanted to write this originally (because you are reading the callablestatement instead of the result of your stored procedure call):

```
ResultSet rs= castat.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
     result = rs.getString(4);
}
```

Of course, the resultset should be closed properly in the finally block.